# Mocking a database in python unittest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, python-mock, pytest-mock

I am trying to mock the value returned by get_count function in unittest mock by mocking sql connection. But I got this error.

AssertionError: 12939 != <MagicMock name='mock.cursor().fetchone().**getitem**()' id='1053090478792'

**app.py**

```
import pyodbc

try:

    def get_count(conn):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM mydb.dbo.Company')
        count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        return count
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = 'xx.x.xx.xxx'
    database = 'mydb' 
    username = 'user1' 
    password = '12424124'
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print(get_count(conn))
```

**test_count.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from app import get_count
class Test_count(unittest.TestCase):

    def fix_dbc(self):
        dbc = mock.MagicMock(spec=['cursor'])
        return dbc

    def fix_count(self):    
        count = 12939
        return count

    def test_get_count_method(self):
        dbc = self.fix_dbc()
        count = self.fix_count()
        self.assertEqual(count, get_count(dbc))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['', '-v'])
```

This is my code anyone help me

Comment: why do you have `try/except` around your function declaration? doesn't make much sense, you probably meant to put it inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

You left in the middle of mock initialization: `dbc` is a magick Mock that you give to  `get_count`. So you will get `dbc.cursor().fetchone()[0]` after calling other methods on `dbc.cursor()`.

You must configure your mock to return the appropriate values:

```
def fix_dbc(self):
    dbc = mock.MagicMock(spec=['cursor'],
                         **{'cursor.return_value': mock.MagickMock(
                             spec=['execute', 'fetchone'],
                             **{'fetchone.return_value': [12939]})})
    return dbc
```